# React, Typescipt, Conditional rops

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this type:

```
export type InfoItemProps = (
  | { inputType: 'dropdown-menu'; options: string[] }
  | { inputType: 'text' }
  | { inputType: 'date' }
  | { inputType: 'text-aria' }
  | { inputType: 'phone-number' }
) & {
  name: string;
  labelText: string;
  value: string;
  editValue: string;
  editMode: boolean;
  onEditValueChange: (inputName: string, value: string) => void;
};
```

But whenever i try to access options it complains that:

```
Property 'options' does not exist on type 
'{ inputType: "text"; } & { name: string; labelText: string; value: string;
 editValue: string; editMode: boolean; onEditValueChange: (inputName: string, value: string) => void; }'.
```

What is going on? How to fix it?

Comment: You can only access options if it's inside a conditional statement / switch e.g. `const info: InfoItemProps.....` `if(info.inputType === 'dropdown-menu') { // you can access options here }`

Comment: show you tsconfig please. You code works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if inputType === 'dropdown-menu':

```js
export type InfoItemProps = (
  | { inputType: 'dropdown-menu'; options: string[] }
  | { inputType: 'text' }
  | { inputType: 'date' }
  | { inputType: 'text-aria' }
  | { inputType: 'phone-number' }
) & {
  name: string;
  labelText: string;
  value: string;
  editValue: string;
  editMode: boolean;
  onEditValueChange: (inputName: string, value: string) => void;
};

declare var obj: InfoItemProps;

if (obj.inputType === 'dropdown-menu') {
  obj.options // ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also declare `options` in other input types. Since they are nothing, you can type them as `undefined` and make it optional:

```
export type InfoItemProps = (
  | { inputType: 'dropdown-menu'; options: string[] }
  | { inputType: 'text'; options?: undefined }
  | { inputType: 'date'; options?: undefined }
  | { inputType: 'text-aria'; options?: undefined }
  | { inputType: 'phone-number'; options?: undefined }
) & {
  name: string;
  labelText: string;
  value: string;
  editValue: string;
  editMode: boolean;
  onEditValueChange: (inputName: string, value: string) => void;
};
```

See it [in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7AZhNNgC2AClBGAM5wC8cAFAFBxwA+cA3nAJYZgCuMAFWTAAXHADkAE1JhJEAO4YAtAWAZe4gNxwyMThAzkx5GFG4BzANoBdOAF9GLdlx78hKMePwgYWnWD0DcgB+MV4MSWAsbmBJe0dWDm4+QWFPSQBDfD9dfUNQuHDI6IxY+KZElxT3UQlvGCUMswycgLyQsIiomLiHCudktzSJMAALA2AldQIAI2AoVsD8zuKe+IBKOAAydkcMDNVjUwtNRwAbDLmzgVAYI7MMc1OmADcMs95akwenx1jOGAANXen3uJz+kgBAFkIJExDMIBAzsAMhhnjoMABRSFAkHAADCo1R5lqtEGMAAcgcvsdHgAaOBvD40n6bKgAPkZEE4klOdlO9AAxkF4KADmBkWJMDg8IQSGRKDQ2HY4BlKKjEALhYZ4LkgtQ4GKCBLgAA6PWGTRAA).